# How can I silence deprecation warnings on my own methods with 'sbt test'?

Tags: scala, sbt, deprecated, scalatest

I have a method in one of my libraries that I’ve deprecated:

```
@deprecated(
  "Use one of the specific count{Success,RecognisedFailure,Failure} methods",
  "messaging 1.1")
def count( ... ): Future[T] = { ... }
```

In my build.sbt, I check for deprecation warnings and turn warnings into errors.  I want to know about deprecations in other libraries I use, and warnings-as-errors has helped keep us on our toes about good coding practices.

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-deprecation",
  "-Xfatal-warnings",
  ...
)
```

And I have tests that exercise the deprecated method, that predate the deprecation.  The test class uses `FunSpec` from Scalatest, and I run the tests with `sbt test`.

I'd like to keep those tests until I actually remove the method – just because it's deprecated doesn't mean I'm allowed to let it break.

Here's my issue: the compiler is seeing my deprecation warning, upgrading it to an error, and refusing to run `sbt test`:

```
[error] MetricsSenderTest.scala:53:25: method count in class MetricsSender
        is deprecated (since messaging 1.0): Use one of the specific
        count{Success,RecognisedFailure,Failure} methods
[error]           metricsSender.count(metricName, f)
[error]                         ^
```

So I either have to remove my `@deprecated` annotation, or not run with warnings-as-errors, both of which seem not ideal.

**Is there a way I can tell Scala “hey, it’s okay if this test case calls a deprecated method”?**

(Or even better, “this test case should call a deprecated method, and if it doesn’t that’s a bug”?)

---

I've done a variety of Google searches with various permutations on “scalatest”, “deprecations”, “warnings”, but all I can find is instructions on how to emit deprecation warnings, turn warnings into errors, or get deprecation warnings from the compiler – and I already know how to do those!

Comment: I _think_ that if mark your test class/method itself as deprecated, it shouldn't issue the warning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to suppress deprecation warnings when testing deprecated Scala functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52837691/how-to-suppress-deprecation-warnings-when-testing-deprecated-scala-functions)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding "-unchecked" to `scalacOptions`?

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-unchecked",
  "-deprecation",
  "-Xfatal-warnings",
  ...
)
```